# Using Material-UI KeyboardTimePicker, how can you change the time without changing the date?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker, timepicker, date-fns

I have a React app using Material-UI's KeyboardTimePicker

The KeyboardTimePicker has a default value set at "June 10 2021 at 12:00"

If I use the picker popup to change the time, it works fine.

But if I use the textfield to modify the time, it also changes the date to the current date.

https://codesandbox.io/s/keyboardtimepicker-bug-zqeh4?file=/src/App.tsx

How can I ensure that only the time changes when the user uses the keyboard to change the time?

thank you

[Edit] The problem also exists in material-ui Next.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26799

https://codesandbox.io/s/keyboardtimepicker-bug-material-ui-next-mbmy6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that outcome by using the `setHours()` `getHours()` `getMinutes()`.etc. methods that come with the Date object.

I have made a solution that does what you intend to do, which is only to change the hours and the minutes of your state by using the aforementioned methods.

```
 const changeTimeOnly = useCallback(
    (time: Date | null) => {
      if (time) {
        if (!isNaN(time.getHours()) && !isNaN(time.getMinutes()))
          handleDateChange((date) => {
            if (date) {
              date.setHours(time.getHours(), time.getMinutes());
              return new Date(date);
            }
            return null;
          });
      }
    },
    [handleDateChange]
  );
```

[codesandbox solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/keyboardtimepicker-bug-forked-lghhe?file=/src/App.tsx)

Keep in mind that the time you print, might be different than the time the timepicker sets depending on your local timezone.

Comment: This is a great workaround, thanks. But I still believe that this was a bug in material-ui, since using the picker component doesn't have the same behavior as inputing with the keyboard

Comment: Yes, it is definitely not expected behavior. Since you've created an issue on their repo they should have a look at it sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript Date object supports a number of UTC (universal) methods, as well as local time methods. UTC, also known as Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), refers to the time as set by the World Time Standard. The local time is the time known to the computer where JavaScript is executed.

You may need to set the timezone, may be using moment.

https://codesandbox.io/s/keyboardtimepicker-bug-forked-zoyix

Comment: This doesn't work. Changing the time using the keyoard resets the date to today's date. I need to save the whole date and have only the time part user-modifiable